# Java infinite loop in despite of statement makes condition false

Tags: java, while-loop

I am new on Java, but my problem can be language independent.
I have a Player class and in my game logic, i have a map stores created players.
I write a method -`getNext()`- that returns the next player to me and it works like a charm. But in the game, players that eliminated must not get in line. So I write a new method -`getNextAlive()`- should return next alive (!isLoser) player. If there isn't any loser player, getNextAlive() is working but if there is, program gets in while loop and looping infinitely. In while loop I switch to next player and sure that next is alive, but I think `while(p.checkLose())` not affected in while changes and give this output forever:

player: allyozturk

I can't get why this happens in this way, what should I do for skipping all isLoser players and get the next alive one? (BTW, I use libgdx ArrayMap and my map is ordered because of order of next player is importont for my game)

in-game I use:

```
currPlayer = currPlayer.getNextAlive();
```

and here my Player.java is:

```
    public class Player{
        private static int counter;
        public static int alives;

        private int uniqueId;
        private String name;
        private boolean isLoser;
        .
        .
        .
        private Player getNext(){
            int index = MyGdxGame.players.indexOfKey(uniqueId);
            if(++index < MyGdxGame.players.size)
                return MyGdxGame.players.getValueAt(index);
            else
                return MyGdxGame.players.getValueAt(0);
        }

        public Player getNextAlive(){
            Player p = getNext();
            while(p.checkLose()){
                p = getNext();
                MyGdxGame.logger.error("player: " + p.getName()); // just for testing purpose
            }
            return p;
        }
    }
```

And an addition question coming from some curiosity and some for doing the best: Is it totally appropriate that using a method returns Player in the Player class?

Comment: Debug your index value while the program is running.

Comment: Where is your `checkLose()` functionality?

Comment: IMHO, the methods to return another valid player should be in your `MyGdxGame`, not in the `Player`itself. Maybe that could make things easier to understand.

Comment: @AlbertodePaola so this means that return same class object is not matter except clean coding?

Comment: @AsheraH sorry I didn't think that is essential 'cause it so simply makes isLoser true or false just for now.

Comment: @allyozturk return same class object is fine and used in some patterns. But I think the responsibility to know who is the next alive player is where the list of players is, in `MyGdxGame`. The `Player` class knows only about wether itself is alive or not.

Comment: yeah it makes sense. thanks for the answers.

Comment: @allyozturk you are welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `p = getNext();` with `p = p.getNext();`

Comment: yes, in your loop, the player is always calling the next on himself in the loop, not getting the "nextPlayers" next player

Comment: I've just realized that and came here for deleting my question and saw that it's too late :) ok I feel so stupid now and should delete this question but for the others like me, just be more careful :)